# Get Recents Calls List on Xamain.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a use case where I need to get the last x incoming/outgoing calls to the mobile.

Is there a direct way to do it? (I would imagine that will require permissions)
And if not, how would I start on this?

Note that I prefer a way to do it on Forms instead of platform specific code if possible as I need it for both Android and iPhone devices.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: there is no way to do this on iOS

Comment: For android,you need to use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/) to do it in the android project.